# Can I use declare-const to eliminate the forall universal quantifier?

Tags: z3, theorem-proving

I have some confusion of using universal quantifier and declare-const without using forall

```
(set-option :mbqi true)
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-const b Int)

(assert (forall ((x Int)) (>= (f x x) (+ x a))))
```

I can write like this:

```
(declare-const x Int)
(assert  (>= (f x x) (+ x a))))
```

with Z3 will explore all the possible values of type Int in this two cases. So what's the difference?
Can I really use the declare-const to eliminate the forall quantifier?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the statements are different.  Constants in Z3 are nullary (0 arity) functions, so `(declare-const a Int)` is just syntactic sugar for `(declare-fun a () Int)`, so these two statements are identical.  Your second statement `(assert  (>= (f x x) (+ x a))))` implicitly asserts existence of x, instead of for all x as in your first statement `(assert (forall ((x Int)) (>= (f x x) (+ x a))))`.  To be clear, note that in your second statement, only a single assignment for x needs to satisfy the assertion, not all possible assignments (also note the difference in the function f, and see this Z3@rise script: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/4cif ).

Here's the text of that script:

```
(set-option :mbqi true)
(declare-fun f (Int Int) Int)
(declare-const a Int)
(declare-fun af () Int)
(declare-const b Int)
(declare-fun bf () Int)

(push)
(declare-const x Int)
(assert  (>= (f x x) (+ x a)))
(check-sat) ; note the explicit model value for x: this only checks a single value of x, not all of them
(get-model)
(pop)

(push)
(assert (forall ((x Int)) (>= (f x x) (+ x a))))
(check-sat)
(get-model) ; no model for x since any model must satisfy assertion
(pop)
```

Also, here's an example from the Z3 SMT guide ( http://rise4fun.com/z3/tutorial/guide from under the section "Uninterpreted functions and constants"):

```
(declare-fun f (Int) Int)
(declare-fun a () Int) ; a is a constant
(declare-const b Int) ; syntax sugar for (declare-fun b () Int)
(assert (> a 20))
(assert (> b a))
(assert (= (f 10) 1))
(check-sat)
(get-model)
```

Answer (score 5):

You can eliminate a top-level `exists` with a `declare-const`. Maybe this is the source of your confusion? The following two are equivalent:

```
    (assert (exists ((x Int)) (> x 0)))
    (check-sat)
```

and

```
   (declare-fun x () Int)
   (assert (> x 0))
   (check-sat)
```

Note that this only applies to top-level existential quantifiers. If you have nested quantification of both universals (`forall`) and existentials (`exists`), then you can do skolemization to float the existentials to the top level. This process is more involved but rather straightforward from a logical point of view.

There is no general way of floating universal quantifiers to the top-level in this way, at least not in classical logic as embodied by SMT-Lib.